# (Solved) i have problem with Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN Drivers on Elementary OS (Wifi is disabled all the tiem no drivers working)

Tags: wifi, drivers

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install

its worked finally

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you tried [this](https://github.com/bserem/Realtek-RTL8822x-Linux)? Try `Realtek 8822CE +linux` at your favorite search engine for more options.

Comment: can you give me detail information how to install this please ?

Comment: Edit: finally its worked.. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88